# Aura Sync crashes when graphics tablet is plugged in

Tags: windows-10, drivers, touchscreen

TLDR: Aura Sync RGB lighting software crashes with touchscreen is plugged in.

I run a ROG Strix Z390F-Gaming with a 9900K, windows 10 build 1809 and 3 monitors - 2 4k monitors on a Gforce 980TI and I recently installed [a XPpen Artist Display 10S](https://www.xp-pen.com/product/56.html) on the onboard intel video adaptor . Aura Sync will immediately crash showing an error message that auraservice is not running. Since the touchscreen was the last thing I installed, I tried without it.

The touchscreen connects at the device over USB C and connects to my PC via HDMI, one USB port for the touch/pen interface and a last USB that's just for power.

I've tried various versions of the aura sync software Lighting_Control_1.07.60, Lighting_Control_1.07.66 and Lighting_Control_1.07.17. I also experimented with a full removal and reinstall.

The XP pen uses the Artist10S for Win(5543) beta driver.

Essentially aura sync crashes if the touchscreen is plugged in.

[image: Error window saying "AuraService is currently unavailable. Please close AUra and check if AuraService is installed and started Properly]]

From what I can tell from the event viewer, its due to HID.DLL. However *if* the tablet's data USB connector is unplugged  at startup, the application works fine.

[image: Screenshot of event viewer]

An additional point is the touchscreen driver has an option to restrict touch screen control to one screen (which is essential in a multimonitor configuration). its *not* running when the touchscreen is unplugged. It automatically starts if its plugged in, but since aura/(lighting service?) is already running, there's no conflict

[image: screenshot of the tablet config application]

My guess is this hooks into the HID.DLL - as does aura (presumably for HID support)

I'm curious to what's happening, and how I can get these two pieces of software to get along. In theory, aura isn't something I play with a lot, but its nice to not have to reach behind my PC and reboot every time I want to adjust or turn off my lighting.

I suspect that the services in question are wintab32 for the graphics tablet and LightingService for Aura

I'd note aura runs fine *if* it starts the touchscreen isn't plugged in (and that activates automatically when the touchscreen is started).

I've tried delayed start on the wintab service with no result

Comment: If the touchscreen driver uses and independent service, did you try to setup its startup option to delayed in services.msc

Answer (score 1):

Asus Aura Sync is a very buggy software, and new versions did not fix it. The error "AuraService is currently unavailable" is affecting many users trying to fix it. It is necessary to do a proper cleaning of previous versions of Aura before trying another. After that, for some users one of the new versions -1.06XX, 1.07XX- worked, but for others (like me) they needed to user an older Aura -0.0.XX-, typically one for your specific device, if available (*). I provide steps for everything below:

- Uninstall all Aura-related software
- Restart PC
- Run the Asus Aura Cleaner tool (if available; see (*) below)
- Run the following script from PowerShell as administrator (you may save it as a .ps1 file). This will uninstall the "Program Files\ASUS*" programs if any:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
Get-ChildItem "D:\Downloads\Lighting_Control_1.07.71\LightingService\aac" -Filter *.exe | 
Foreach-Object {
    $params = "/uninstall", "/passive", "/norestart"
    & $_.FullName $params
}`

- If there is any Aura-related folders in Program Files or Program Files (x86), delete them manually
- Run CCleaner (or similar registry cleaner program) to clean registry of left Aura-related entries
- Restart PC
- Choose the Aura version you are going to install, and download the ZIP.
- Before extracting, open the ZIP properties and check the check box "Unblock" [[1]](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/914483-asus-lighting-software-help-solved/?tab=comments#comment-11223464)
- Extract it. If there is a subfolder "LightingService", get in and install first "AuraServiceSetup.exe". Afterwards, "AsusSetup.exe" [[2]](https://hardforum.com/threads/asus-prime-x570-pro-aura-sync-issues.1985432/#post-1044368028)
- Restart PC
- Try Aura. If it crashes, start again trying another version.

(*) It seems for some devices, Asus Support still keeps older versions of Aura specific for that device (hidden after a "show all"). For others, that is not available anymore, and old links just give a 404 [[3]](https://egpu.io/forums/thunderbolt-enclosures/asus-xg-station-pro-short-review-and-some-problems/). There are users sharing older versions in Google Drive[[4]](https://rog.asus.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-101543-p-2.html). The most complete currently available [is this one](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11WA9pqhPv6B0jF3DKEPeWzwlog3Hdakm), which includes the Aura Cleaner tool and multiple versions of Aura Sync.

Comment: Tried all that - and listed the versions I've tried. Its just a little stranger, and unfortunately possibly specific to my specific hardware setup.Aura works fine *if* the touch display is removed. Its all manner of fun.